# OpenCV - using cv2.canny and cv2.findContours to find area with data on the heterogeneous images

Tags: python, image, opencv, object-detection, image-recognition

This is my first question here so I'm asking for understanding. I have to process hundreds of the satellites images.
I try to find contour of the area of the useful data located on the image - only the largest one.
[image] Then I want to save the coordinates of the few points (x,y) corresponding to this contour.  In simplest case,  the area is a square and can be represented by 4 points, but for more complicated shapes the contour will be approximated by a little more points (preferably no more than ~ fifteen). However I am still not be able to find the areas on my images. Sometimes the area touches the edge of the image. Therefore, in this script I enlarge the pictures and add additional boundaries filled by the background color. Examples of pictures you will find here [satellite1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nPv6.jpg),[satellite2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRX7h.jpg),[satellite3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGBRl.jpg)
As you see the images can have different background colors and in addition they contain countries borders and legend. I have tried to use Aidenhjj tips  [OpenCV - using cv2.approxPolyDP() correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41879315/opencv-using-cv2-approxpolydp-correctly) and prepared my script. I tried many approaches, filtering and tune parameters but still can't succeed with my data. I am asking you for help.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = cv2.imread('image1.jpg')
image = cv2.resize(image, None,fx=0.25, fy=0.25, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
ysize, xsize, channels = image.shape
print("Image size: {} x {}".format(xsize, ysize))

#calculate the histograms in r,g,b channels, measure background color
r, g, b = cv2.split(image)
image_data = image

histr = cv2.calcHist([r],[0],None,[256],[0,256])
for y in range(0,len(histr)):
    elem = histr[y]
    if elem == histr.max():
     break
else:
    y = none
R=y

histr = cv2.calcHist([g],[0],None,[256],[0,256])
for y in range(0,len(histr)):
    elem = histr[y]
    if elem == histr.max():
     break
else:
    y = none
G=y

histr = cv2.calcHist([b],[0],None,[256],[0,256])
for y in range(0,len(histr)):
    elem = histr[y]
    if elem == histr.max():
     break
else:
    y = none
B=y
color = (R, G, B)

#add borders around the image colorized as background. This will allow me to find closed contour around area with data.
bordersize=100
new_xsize = xsize + bordersize*2
new_ysize = ysize + bordersize*2
#image_border.show()
image_border=cv2.copyMakeBorder(image, top=bordersize, bottom=bordersize, left=bordersize, right=bordersize, borderType= cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=[R,G,B] )

#ysizeb, xsizeb, channelsb = image_border.shape

# get a blank canvas for drawing contour on and convert image to grayscale
canvas = np.zeros(image_border.shape, np.uint8)
#imgc = cv2.medianBlur(img,21)
img2gray = cv2.cvtColor(image_border,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# filter out country borders
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.float32)/25
img2gray = cv2.filter2D(img2gray,-1,kernel)

# threshold the image and extract contours
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img2gray,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,11)
contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
plt.subplot(111),plt.imshow(thresh,'gray')
plt.show()
# find the biggest area
cnt = contours[0]

max_area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)

for cont in contours:
    if cv2.contourArea(cont) > max_area:
        cnt = cont
        max_area = cv2.contourArea(cont)
perimeter = cv2.arcLength(cnt,True)
epsilon = 0.01*cv2.arcLength(cnt,True)
approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt,epsilon,True)

hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt)

# cv2.isContourConvex(cnt)
cv2.drawContours(canvas, cnt, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
cv2.drawContours(canvas, approx, -1, (0, 0, 255), 3)
#cv2.drawContours(canvas, [hull], -1, (0, 0, 255), 3) 

cv2.imshow("Contour", canvas)
k = cv2.waitKey(0)

if k == 27:         # wait for ESC key to exit
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Hey rudypl2, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please have a look at [this little guide for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and consider editing your question to be a bit clearer, and perhaps include some examples of what you've already tried to solve this problem.

Comment: Do your images look binarized correctly after applying the threshold?

Comment: Hi Alexander. Unfortunately, the images after threshold  do not look good (a lot of strange shapes - detected clouds and country borders. I think my problem to first filter out all borders as well as other colorful structures.